# Current usefulness of semantically correct HTML

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm working on a new website, and I'm trying to decide how I want to balance the need for semantic correctness, with other important stuff, like development time. I know that semantics are supposed to be important for SEO, and accessibility for blind people. And those are important to me, and shouldn't take too much extra time. So I'll design them in, from the beginning. Anyway, my question is, what else is semantic correctness *currently* useful for? If there's something else I may consider worthwhile, I'd rather spend a little extra time now to build it in, than wait until later, when it may be more difficult.

Also, I know there are a lot of future possibilities. Some good, and some not (I've seen all the Terminator movies:). But I'll wait and see what happens with those.

edit: I should have mentioned that supporting some old browsers is important for this project, so being semantically correct won't be easy. Especially since I haven't done a lot of browser programming.

Comment: Besides avoiding issues with browser's rendering engine with invalid markup for example? Or with responsiveness? And this are not just details while developing a website

Comment: It adds alot of readability as well, and thus, increases maintainability.

Comment: Accessibility is not only for blind people, it's for all disabilities (auditory, motor, cognitive, etc.). What are the old browsers you need to support ?

Comment: @Michel - I'm not sure yet how far back I want to go, with browsers. But to give you and idea, Netscape 6 and IE6 are possibilities. Also, I was only thinking about accessibility issues for blind people. But since you mentioned it, I'll look into other disabilities too, and see what's needed for supporting them.

Comment: @Michel - I've been reading up a bit on accessibility (not just for blind people), and I think it's going to be much more important than I originally thought. I haven't seen anything new yet, regarding HTML semantics though. Anyway, thanks for mentioning it, because it's going to help me make some better design decisions.

Comment: @Lelio - Do you mean that making things semantically correct, will allow you to better use HTML validators? If that's what you mean, I agree that all else being equal, being semantically correct could help. But couldn't I be semantically incorrect, and still have valid HTML? For my purposes, I'm thinking I'll be better off not worrying too much about semantics with old browsers, as long as it's acceptable for SEO and accessibility.

Comment: @connexo - If I wasn't trying to support older browsers, I think I'd agree with you. But I haven't done a lot of programming yet for browsers, so there's a lot I don't know yet. Most of my experience is backend, and Delphi GUI's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research, so now I can answer my own question.

Other than making sure my site is accessible to disabled people and search engines, there isn't currently anything all that important about semantic correctness, for my project. And I think search engines and screen readers are sophisticated enough these days, to handle some incorrect semantics, as long as the content structure isn't too confusing.

I can see semantic HTML elements being useful for documentation though, as long as it doesn't complicate my code.